# Learning Node.js... curious of scope

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm reading an ebook called "The Node Beginner Book". It's basically 1 huge ~50 page exercise that covers a bunch of basics. I've been workin in python recently, and have php from a past life. So I figured it was right up my alley when this book said it was intended for people "experienced with at least one object-oriented language like Ruby, Python, PHP or Java, only little
experience with JavaScript, and completely new to Node.js."

Here's the context:

---

index.js

```
var server =  require("./server");
var router =  require("./router");
var requestHandlers = require("./requestHandlers");
var handle = {}
handle ["/"] = requestHandlers.start;
handle ["/start"] = requestHandlers.start;
handle ["/upload"] = requestHandlers.upload;

server.start(router.route, handle);
```

---

server.js

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");

function start(route, handle) {
    function onRequest(request, response) {
        var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
        console.log("> Rcvd: " + pathname);

        route(handle, pathname, response);
    }

    http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
    console.log("Server has started");
}

exports.start = start;
```

---

router.js

```
function route(handle, pathname, response) {
    console.log("Routing: " + pathname);
    if (typeof handle[pathname] === 'function'){
        return handle[pathname](response);
    } else {
        console.log("ReqH ERR: No handler for " + pathname);
        response.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        response.write("404 Not Found");
        response.end();
    }
}

exports.route = route;
```

---

requestHandlers.js

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;

function start(response) {
    console.log("Request handler 'start' was called.");
    var content = "empty";

    exec("ls -lah", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        response.write(stdout);
        response.end();
    });

    return content;
}

function upload(response){
    console.log("ReqH: upload");
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("From upload()");
    response.end();
}

exports.start = start;
exports.upload = upload;
```

And then you start the app via `node index.js`.

Alright I see that the "order of execution", or the path that the app takes, begins with including `server.js` and `router.js`, so I understand that basically the app 'lives' in index.js, running errands and going to work in the other modules.

Here's the question... `server.js` refers to the function `route()`, but doesn't explicitly require `router.js` which is the module that defines `route()`.

Does `index.js` set the scope for the modules that it included? Since `router.route` is included in `index`, does `server` get access to `index`es scope without having to explicitly know where `route()` came from?

Javascript is so loose that these 'lazy' kinda things are proving kinda challenging to wrap my head around.

Comment: The function is passed here server.start(router.route, handle);

Answer (score 3):

it would be good to read up about CommonJS -> http://requirejs.org/docs/commonjs.html

#### index.js

```
var server =  require("./server");
var router =  require("./router");

...
// here you are passing in the route method as the route param
server.start(router.route, handle);
```

so what it's actually doing is calling the start function in server.js and passign router.route as the parameter 'route'

#### server.js

```
   var http = require("http");
    var url = require("url");
    
    // here route is just the name of the param 
    function start(route, handle) {
        function onRequest(request, response) {
            var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
            console.log("> Rcvd: " + pathname);
    
            route(handle, pathname, response);
        }
    
        http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
        console.log("Server has started");
    }
    
    exports.start = start;
```

here you are exporting the start function and thats why you can access it like this `var server = require('./server').start(router.route, handle)` in index.js

Comment: Actually, now that you point it out, the author actually explained that. As I was lookin at the code following it around, I guess I forgot that he said that. Bottom line is that start() isn't referring to anything, it's just dealing with what it's been given. Thanks.

Comment: Because `var server = require('./server')` and `exports.start = start` is CommonJS syntax and it's important to understand what's actually happening behind the scenes, less magic more clarity...;)